# Bootstrap 4 carousel data-slide-to based on data-id (Jquery)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap-4

I have a little problem at the moment with my bootstrap 4 carousel. I'm looking to use the indicators based on indicator passing the data id that I have chosen myself. As you can see from the code, some of my slides skip a number, depending on the whether an image was uploaded. that means I need my carousel to link the slides my indicators, rather than by order in which they are in the container.

I have tried using the solution from a similar question posted below, however that was for bootstrap3 and it doesn't seem to work for me.

[Bootstrap carousel data-slide link issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19950295/bootstrap-carousel-data-slide-link-issue)

The script I used is seen below, if I write on my slides that the first slide is data-id=222 then in my indicator I want to say data-slide-to="222". I have written this, that script should of worked like it did for the other person. I can't see why it would make a big difference between bootstrap3 or bootstrap4.

any help or push in the right direction would be appreciated.

```
<script>
                $('.carousel-indicators li').click(function(e){
                    e.stopPropagation();
                    var goTo = $(this).data('slide-to');
                  $('.carousel-inner .carousel-item').each(function(index){
                    if($(this).data('id') == goTo){
                      goTo = index;
                      return false;
                    }
                    
                  });
                    
                    $('#carouselExampleIndicators').carousel(goTo); 
                });
            </script>
        
            <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                <div class="carousel-inner">
                    
                    <div class="carousel-item active car-w" data-id="0">
                        <img class="d-block w-100" alt="watch image" src="/media/jewellery_images/Round_heart_white_1.jpg" />
                    </div>

                    <div class="carousel-item car-w" data-id="1">
                        <img class="d-block w-100" alt="watch image" src="/media/jewellery_images/Round_heart_white_2.jpg" />
                    </div>
                    
                    
                    
                    
                    
                    <div class="carousel-item car-r" data-id="3">
                        <img class="d-block w-100" alt="watch image" src="/media/jewellery_images/Round_heart_rose_1.jpg" />
                    </div>
                    
                    
                    
                    <div class="carousel-item car-r" data-id="4">
                        <img class="d-block w-100" alt="watch image" src="/media/jewellery_images/Round_heart_rose_2.jpg" />
                    </div>
                    
                    
                    
                    
                    
                    <div class="carousel-item car-y" data-id="6">
                        <img class="d-block w-100" alt="watch image" src="/media/jewellery_images/Round_heart_yellow_1.jpg" />
                    </div>
                    
                    
                    
                    <div class="carousel-item car-y" data-id="7">
                        <img class="d-block w-100" alt="watch image" src="/media/jewellery_images/Round_heart_yellow_2.jpg" />
                    </div>
                    

                    
                </div>
                
                <ol class="carousel-indicators list-inline">
                    
                    <li class="list-inline-item active thumb-w"> <a id="carousel-selector-0" data-slide-to="0" data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators"> <img class="img-fluid" alt="watch image" src="/media/jewellery_images/Round_heart_white_1.jpg" /> </a> </li>
                    
                    
                    <li class="list-inline-item thumb-w"> <a id="carousel-selector-1" data-slide-to="1" data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators"> <img class="img-fluid" alt="watch image" src="/media/jewellery_images/Round_heart_white_2.jpg" /> </a> </li>
                    
                    
                    
                    <li class="list-inline-item thumb-r"> <a id="carousel-selector-3" data-slide-to="3" data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators"> <img class="img-fluid" alt="watch image" src="/media/jewellery_images/Round_heart_rose_1.jpg" /> </a> </li>
                    
                    
                    <li class="list-inline-item thumb-r"> <a id="carousel-selector-4" data-slide-to="4" data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators"> <img class="img-fluid" alt="watch image" src="/media/jewellery_images/Round_heart_rose_2.jpg" /> </a> </li>
                    
                    
                    
                    <li class="list-inline-item thumb-y"> <a id="carousel-selector-6" data-slide-to="6" data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators"> <img class="img-fluid" alt="watch image" src="/media/jewellery_images/Round_heart_yellow_1.jpg" /> </a> </li>
                    
                    
                    <li class="list-inline-item thumb-y"> <a id="carousel-selector-7" data-slide-to="7" data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators"> <img class="img-fluid" alt="watch image" src="/media/jewellery_images/Round_heart_yellow_2.jpg" /> </a> </li>
                    
                    
                </ol>
            </div>
```

EDIT: I have made it into a JS fiddle, if that helps.

https://jsfiddle.net/p8jk9xaL/2/

It shows that the slideshow is there but it doesn't change the image upon clicking on the indicators.

Comment: Hi, can you make this runnable ?

Comment: Hi, sorry how do I do that?

Comment: is this what you meant? https://jsfiddle.net/p8jk9xaL/2/

Comment: check if [this](https://jsfiddle.net/76y8dohm/) works for you.